# Rails convert an html email to a text email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

Given an html email message, is there a way to convert that to a text version? I'm doing email ingestion and notice that some times an email doesn't include a text version, especially with blackberry devices.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but couldn't you just take the HTML message and run `ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper#strip_tags` over it?

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-strip_tags

Comment: For others, this does not work. Email clients use PRE tags, which strip_tags removes.

Comment: The premailer gem takes a similar approach, but covers all scenarios. Details in my answer.

Answer (score 8):

HTML to Text is one of the features provided by the [Premailer](https://github.com/alexdunae/premailer/) gem.

```
premailer = Premailer.new('http://example.com/html_email.html')
premailer.to_plain_text
```

In case you don't want to use it because it does a lot, you can look at the code for how it does it [here](https://github.com/alexdunae/premailer/blob/master/lib/premailer/html_to_plain_text.rb)

Comment: The current Premailer gem is linked at https://github.com/premailer/premailer

Comment: Yes was just goign to post that.. i need to customize the html to text and here is the updated version: https://github.com/premailer/premailer/blob/master/lib/premailer/html_to_plain_text.rb

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old, but it comes up high in Google for "convert html to text". The following may meet your needs:

The author says:

> Ruby convert HTML to formatted text — Chip’s Tips for Developers. When
>   you want to have your whitespace and feed it, too.

http://www.chipstips.com/?p=610

Answer (score -3):

Refer the following link 
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

Action mailer provides options for sending a html or text emails.......

Comment: The questioner is talking about received emails, not sending them.